# FFmpeg code throwing error when trying to crop the video: FFmpeg process exited with state COMPLETED and return code 255

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor, ffprobe

Hello I am trying to crop a 9:16 video to a 1:1 video with FFmpeg. The command is throwing this error

```
Exception: FFmpeg process exited with state COMPLETED and return code 255.
```

This is my code:

```
-ss 0:00:00.000000 -i 's879-1696171712815.mp4' -t 0:00:24.149000 -codec:v libx264 -filter:v 'crop=720.0:720.0:0.0:327.25067794421483'   -y 'cropped.mp4'
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thanks